# EasyPost : Unable to create manifest. 5 of the specified shipments have already been manifested:

Tags: c#, usps, easypost

While creating ScanForm EasyPost returns following error. How can I identify if Shipment is manifested or Can't be manifested.

> Unable to create manifest. 5 of the specified shipments have already
>   been manifested: shp_aa, shp_xxx, shp_yy, shp_vv, shp_xx

```
var apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EasyPostAPIKey"];
            EasyPost.ClientManager.SetCurrent(apiKey);

            if (shipmentsPurchasedInDateRange.Count > 0)
            {
                var shipments = new List<EasyPost.Shipment>();
                foreach (var shipmentId in shipmentsPurchasedInDateRange)
                {
                    var shipment = new EasyPost.Shipment()
                    {
                        id = shipmentId,
                    };
                    shipments.Add(shipment);


                }

                var scanForm = ScanForm.Create(shipments);
                return scanForm.form_url;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to manifest multiple shipments its recommended creating a batch with all the shipments. Some Carriers require all shipments to be manifested so what is recommended is creating a single batch for all shipments created in a day and then manifesting that batch.

Here's the workflow:
Create Shipments for the day
At the end of the day create a Batch.
When creating a batch you can create it with the shipment ID's in an array.
Alternatively you can add shipments to the batch as long as it hasn't been scan formed. This means you could create a batch at the beginning of each day. Then as you create shipments you can just add them to the batch.
After all shipments have been created and added to the batch you can scan form the batch.